# Displaying an "Activity Bar" in an Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, google-play, android-alertdialog

I have an app that requires about 5 seconds upon starting the MainActivity to acquire a GPS fix. The functionality of the app hinges on getting those coordinates, so I have a timer set which turns the GPS on for 5 seconds and then turns it off. While this is running, I need a Dialog box that shows that work is being done.

I would like to have a continually moving "progess" meter exactly like what shows up when you update an app in Google Play. However, I do not want an actual percentage meter. Rather, I want the meter seen below with the gaps in the line racing across.

[image]

The official documentation calls this an "Activity Bar". When I try and search for that term, even using Google Search operators, I get "Android Activity" and "Action Bar".

Anyone else know how I can display this "Activity Bar" in a Dialog, or of any other ways to show it in some kind of modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)?  There are a bunch of different styles available.

Comment: @mattcoker the style you want is called indeterminate

Comment: @stan0 Yup, that's it! Way too difficult to get information on that, and kinda hard to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a process that the front end user has to wait for you can use a thread to execute this process which is provided by android as AsyncTask and like the above answer you can use the progress dialog variance that suits your look to show that the system is processing. You can set the progress dialog cancelable to true if the user wants to exit in between the process.[Here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.UqaiPb8W3Zg) is a good description of using this threading capability given by android. The progress dialog can be used in the onpreExecute module inside the asyncTask thread. And also [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-transparent-progress-dialog-on-android/) is a way you can customize a progress dialog too. I hope this helps.